# Why does gitlab freeze when I clone/pull my repo?

Tags: macos, gitlab

i've created a private repo on gitlab.

from my office's macbook i can clone, pull, push and whatever, but here at home (with a little older macbook), when i try to clone the repo, it stuck on "compressing objects" with a different percentage each time...
no matter how big the repo is (i'm trying to clone a 5KB project..)

eg:

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:username/myproject.git
Cloning into 'myproject'...
remote: Counting objects: 24, done.
remote: Compressing objects:  26% (6/23)
```

i can leave it here for hours (actually i tried for about 30 minutes..)
but the only thing i can do is hit "ctrl+c" and kill the process, then it says

```
Killed by signal 2.
fatal: index-pack failed
```

i'm using:

```
OSX 10.9.4
git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)
```

i tried also to create the folder, then

```
git init
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:username/myproject.git
git pull
```

but the result still the same as cloning the whole project

btw.. searching online i found this answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/22798706/1294988 ) so i tried to execute:

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/0X1A/dotfiles.git
```

and it did it quick and easy! so what's wrong with mine?

any help?